# How to interpret beta coefficients of a generalized linear model using inverse gaussian

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interpretation, regression-coefficients, inverse-gaussian-distribution

I made a generalized linear model with an inverse gaussian link.

```
glm(lone_total ~ class + age + basic_needs_covered_id,
      data = mod_data_lone,
      family = gaussian(link = "inverse")
      )
```

I have chosen this family and link because of the diagnostic plots, which were bad for `inverse.gaussian(link="1/mu^2")` or `Gamma(link="log")` (See distribution of outcome variable in the image below)

The results with the following coefficients:

```
    Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)             0.784873   0.066836  11.743  < 2e-16 ***
class2                 -0.070565   0.067936  -1.039    0.300    
class3                  0.171242   0.203703   0.841    0.401    
age                     0.003912   0.003444   1.136    0.257    
basic_needs_covered_id -0.110093   0.026307  -4.185  4.1e-05 ***
```

how do I interpret the Estimates? I tried to interpret them like betas from gamma or poisson models, or to run log() and exp() on them, but nothing really made sense to me.

**Descriptives of the Data**

```
> str(mod_data_lone)
'data.frame':   229 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ lone_total            : num  0.01 3 3 1 1 1 0.01 3 0.01 0.01 ...
 $ class                 : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 2 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ age                   : num  -14.44 -8.27 7.38 NA 13.99 ...
 $ basic_needs_covered_id: num  0 4 0 2 1 2 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ education_id          : num  6 8 6 6 6 2 6 6 6 6 ...
```

The following image shows the barplot and density distributions and means by class of the observations:

[image: barplot and density distributions]

### -

another table I got is the following, which shows different types of B (which all do not really make sense to me...)

[image: different types of B]

### -

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you tell us something about the data?

Comment: Did you intend to use an inverse link with a Gaussian family distribution (`family=gaussian(link = "inverse"`), or a true inverse-Gaussian family (`family=inverse.gaussian(link = "1/mu^2"`)? In either case, please explain why you make that choice by editing the question. Comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @EdM and (at) utobi: I have edited my question, tried to provide the information and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what I need

**Y=1/(β2X2+β1X1+β0)**

from here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GlmSimulatoR/vignettes/exploring_links_for_the_gaussian_distribution.html

**Example 1:**
Person from Class 3, mean Age and basic_needs_covered = 4

*1/(0.78+0.17+4*(-0.11)) = 1.96*

**Example 2:**
Person from Class 2, mean Age and basic_needs_covered = 4

*1/(0.78-0.07+4*(-0.11)) = 3.70*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In a generalized linear model, a link function $g()$ defines the association between the expected outcome $y$ and the $k$ corresponding predictor values $x_j$:

$$g(y)=\beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^k \beta_i x_j.$$

If you specify an inverse link in your model, $g(y)= 1/y$, then it will be difficult to have an easy interpretation of associations of individual coefficients with outcome, because you then have:

$$y=\frac{1}{\beta_0 + \sum_{j=1}^k \beta_i x_j} .$$

Even without interactions among predictors, the association of any one predictor with outcome thus depends on the values of the others. You can still use that formula for predictions, however, as your answer illustrates.

With a numeric outcome scale representing increasing values of loneliness, this type of data might instead be modeled via [ordinal logistic regression](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/). With a logit link, the individual predictor coefficients then have reasonably straightforward interpretations in terms of changes in the log-odds of changing the outcome by 1 level, given that other predictor values are held constant.